# Extracting all matching (or close to) values between given START n-th and END n-th values / using Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, power-query, microsoft-excel-365

Consider having two tables. Table1(T1) has Date/Time and Pressure value columns and Table2(T2) has also Date/Time and Info values columns.

T1 is showing pressure change through time, for instance: 21.11.2019 19:25:15 with 147 mbar and it is changing basically per minute, 21.11.2019 19:26:15 with 198 mbar and so on...
T2 is slightly different, it can be observed as a table of pairs with START and END instances or in the case of original files (start / finished values). Those values are originally extracted from Log file from our system where all Datalogs are saved. It is a log where you can trace what is/has happening within the system.

**Output:**
What I actually need is to have all the values (Date/time and pressure (P7)) that fall in between those START and END values, that are matching those pairs from T2.

Something like this:
[image: T2]

[image]

Additionally, when I wrote "START n-th" and "END n-th value" in the header description, I am looking **to have 5th minute value** as START value, for instance if the START is on 21.11.2019 19:25 with 147 mbar, I need 21.11.2019 19:30 with 198 mbar, and as END not the last value but one before ending in the same period, for instance last value is on 21.11.2019 13:00 and I need one on 21.11.2019 12:59...I hope this makes sense to you, it is a bit tricky.

Check the SS below for instructions and what I need as "5th minute".

[image: Explaining 5th mninute]

**Things to pay attention** and what I realise that is affecting correct matching between tables are the :seconds in Date/time column (for both T1 and T2). As long as there are not exact (Date/Time) matches between two tables the query crashes...is there a way to make it to look for a minute match and not exactly second? If not second then minute...something like that..

Second problem might occur when there are more "pairs" within one day, as you might notice from the T2, it is usually one pair per day, but there are and will be cases where it will be more "start / end" instances within one day.

Third thing to notice is that it might be possible that even though you have pairs in T2 but there are no values that are falling between those dates from T1 (it is internal problem with a system itself where we didnt receive the data in certain period), but in that case query should proceed further without giving an error, and provide another matches on the way.

I am providing the queries that I have been using but they dont give me proper results:

***First code*** is very slow and it loads forever the data...but still doesnt fullfil its duty.

***Tables:*** **Parameters => T1
Log_Original => T2**

```
let Source = Table.Buffer(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date/Time", type datetime}, {"P7 [mbar]", Int64.Type}}),
//get start/stop times table
Source2 = Table.Buffer(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Log_Original"]}[Content]),
typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2, {"Date/Time", type datetime}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(typeIt, each ([#"Date/Time"] <> null)),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Index", 0, 1),
// shift Info up one row for comparison
    shiftedList = List.RemoveFirstN(  #"Added Index"[Info],1),
    custom1 = Table.ToColumns(  #"Added Index") & {shiftedList},
    custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(  #"Added Index") & {"NextInfo"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(custom2, "NextLineStart", each if Text.Contains([Info],"start", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            and  Text.Contains([NextInfo],"start", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        then "delete" 
        else null),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([NextLineStart] = null)),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Type", each if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([Info]),"start") then "start" else if Text.Contains(Text.Lower([Info]),"finished") then "finished" else null),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Info", "NextInfo", "NextLineStart"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom", each if [Type]="start" then [Index] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Index"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns",null,"no data!",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Type"}),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Replaced Value", {{"P7 [mbar]", null}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Replaced Errors", List.Distinct(#"Replaced Errors"[Type]), "Type", "Date/Time"),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column","Table",(i)=>Table.Sort(Table.SelectRows(Parameters, each [#"Date/Time"]>=i[start] and [#"Date/Time"]<=i[finished]),{{"Date/Time", Order.Ascending}}) , type table ),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Zeit/d", "D/T_5min/End", "Log_D/T-End - 1min", "P7 [mbar]", "P_5min / P_End", "Zeit nach Äquilibrierung (5.min) bis Ende [h]", "dp/dt_mittel [Pa/min]", "Custom", "start", "finished", "no data!"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

*Second code* is different, quicker but still it doesnt completely do the homework:

```
 let

//Be sure to change the table names in the Source= and Source2= lines to be the actual table names from your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date/Time", type datetime}, {"P7 [mbar]", Int64.Type}}),
       
//get start/stop times table
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Log_Original"]}[Content],
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2, {"Date/Time", type datetime}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(typeIt, each ([#"Date/Time"] <> null)),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Index", 0, 1),

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "NextLineStart", each if Text.Contains([Info],"start", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = true 
                and Text.Contains(#"Added Index"[Info]{[Index]+1},"start",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = true 
            then "delete" 
            else null),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([NextLineStart] = null)),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Index", "NextLineStart"}),

//create a list of all the relevant start/stop times
     filterTimes = List.Combine(
                        List.Generate(
                            ()=> [times = List.DateTimes(#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{0}, 
                                                        Duration.TotalSeconds(#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{1}-#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{0})+1,
                                                        #duration(0,0,0,1)), IDX = 0],
                            each [IDX] < Table.RowCount(#"Removed Columns1"),
                            each [times = List.DateTimes(#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{[IDX]+2}, 
                                                        Duration.TotalSeconds(#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{[IDX]+3}-#"Removed Columns1"[#"Date/Time"]{[IDX]+2})+1,
                                                        #duration(0,0,0,1)), IDX = [IDX]+2],
                            each [times]
                                    )
                            ),

//filter the table using the list
filterTimesCol = Table.FromList(filterTimes,Splitter.SplitByNothing()),
filteredTable = Table.Join(#"Changed Type","Date/Time",filterTimesCol,"Column1",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(filteredTable,{"Column1"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each DateTime.ToText([#"Date/Time"],"dd-MMM-yy")),
    #"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each [#"Date/Time"] > #datetime(2019, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0)),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows2",{{"Date/Time", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

As last, I am uploading the Test data in google.drive:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10AtLpQuRZriGKWz9vwAoVh7zp6kKKy5n/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101738555398870704584&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 1):

This will I'm sure miss certain parts of your needs, but I think the approach is sound and should get you going down the right road.

**On Table1**:

- Add a column to remove the seconds from the date time
- Add a column to show just the date
- Other formatting changes such as column renames, reordering etc

It looks like this at the end:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date/Time", type datetime}, {"P7 [mbar]", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Date/Time", "date_time"}, {"P7 [mbar]", "p7_mbar"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "date_time_no_seconds", each DateTime.From(DateTime.ToText([date_time],"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"date_time_no_seconds", type datetime}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"date_time", "date_time_no_seconds", "p7_mbar"}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "date_time", "date_time - Copy"),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Duplicated Column",{{"date_time - Copy", type date}}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type2",{{"date_time - Copy", "date_of_date_time"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1"
```

**On Table2**:

- Add a column to remove the seconds from the date time
- Add a column to show just the date
- Add a column containing just the words "Start", "Finished" and "Failed" (I did this using "Custom Column from Examples" so it was pretty easy
- Add a column to list just the C1/C2 values
- Create an index for each row within each date
- Create a group of each 2 rows within each date
- Merge the C1/C2 value with the group created above
- Pivot the start/finished/failed column using the date time without seconds without aggregation

It looks like this at the end:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date/Time", type datetime}, {"Info", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Date/Time", "date_time"}, {"Info", "info"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "date_time_no_seconds", each DateTime.From(DateTime.ToText([date_time],"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"date_time", "date_time_no_seconds", "info"}),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"date_time_no_seconds", type datetime}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type4", "date_time", "date_time - Copy"),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{{"date_time - Copy", "date_of_date_time"}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns1",{{"date_of_date_time", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Custom", each let splitinfo = Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" C", QuoteStyle.None)([info]), splitsplitinfo1 = Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(".", QuoteStyle.None)(splitinfo{1}?) in Text.Combine({Text.Middle(Text.Proper(splitsplitinfo1{0}?), 2), Text.Reverse(Text.Middle(Text.Reverse(splitinfo{0}?), 9))}), type text),
    #"Inserted Kept Characters" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom Column", "Kept Characters", each Text.Select([info], {"0".."9", "C"}), type text),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Kept Characters",{{"Custom", "start_finish"}, {"Kept Characters", "leaktest_name"}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns2",{"info"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"date_of_date_time"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [date_time=nullable datetime, date_of_date_time=nullable date, start_finish=text, leaktest_name=text]}}),
    Indexed = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"date_index", 1, 1)}}),
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Indexed, "Count", {"date_time", "date_time_no_seconds", "date_of_date_time", "start_finish", "leaktest_name", "date_index"}, {"date_time", "date_time_no_seconds", "date_of_date_time.1", "start_finish", "leaktest_name", "date_index"}),
    #"Changed Type5" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Count",{{"date_time_no_seconds", type datetime}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type5",{"date_of_date_time.1"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "test_index", each Number.RoundUp([date_index]/2,0)),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1",{{"test_index", Int64.Type}, {"date_index", Int64.Type}, {"leaktest_name", type text}}),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Merged", each Text.Combine({[leaktest_name], "-", Text.From([test_index], "en-US")}), type text),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"leaktest_name", "date_index", "test_index", "date_time"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns2", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns2"[start_finish]), "start_finish", "date_time_no_seconds"),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Start", type datetime}, {"Finished", type datetime}, {"Failed", type datetime}})
in
    #"Changed Type3"
```

Finally, Merge 1 and 2:

- Merge on date
- Add a column to test whether the mbar date time without seconds is between the start and finish times on that row (**I have not done anything with "Failed", though you may want to**)
- Filter the data set where the test above returns true
- Remove the filter column
- Robert's Your Mother's Brother

It looks like this:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Table2, {"date_of_date_time"}, Table1, {"date_of_date_time"}, "Table1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table1", {"date_time_no_seconds", "p7_mbar"}, {"date_time_no_seconds", "p7_mbar"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table1", "in_range", each [date_time_no_seconds] >= [Start] and [date_time_no_seconds] < [Finished]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([in_range] = true)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"in_range"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: I will check it later on today, will write my observations. Thx in advance

Comment: Hmm okay you did good point but still some parts are missing, almost the same as I had issue. This with seconds was good thing, simple as that actually.
My question, do you have an idea how to get n-th values as I wrote? Those "failed" are also neccessary but I can unfilter them.

Comment: Actually it's not clear what you mean by "5th minute value". Are you saying you want to simply ignore the first n-1 readings in a leaktest?

Comment: I am looking to have 5th minute value as START value, for instance if the START is on 21.11.2019 19:25 with 147 mbar, I need 21.11.2019 19:30 with 198 mbar, and as END not the last value but one before ending in the same period, for instance last value is on 21.11.2019 13:00 and I need one on 21.11.2019 12:59

Yes, starting point is n-1 (for instance as it is in original data: 19:25) but I want to 19:30, so 5 min+ value.... and for ending value, just before last value within the dates....

Comment: Thanks, but that's almost word for word what's in your original post, so it doesn't really clarify anything. I'm sure it's a translation issue that I'm not getting here.

Comment: I updated with a new screenshot for a bit more insights..